# OpenID existing risks -CISSP

Tags: openid

everyone! I am studing CISSP, and I have an question which I can not understand why.

The question is:

*What danger is created by allowing the OpenlD relying party to control the connection to the OpenlD provider?*

My answer is:

*The relying party may be able to steal the client's usename and password.*

I think that the userID and password must be send to the openID provider, so relying party can get then if relying party can control the provider.
But true answer is:

*It creates the possibility of a phishing attack by sending data to a fake OpenlD provider.*

I can not understand what the difference between phishing and stealing passwords, and why should choose phishing.

Could anyone give me some advice? Thanks!

Final, my English is poor, please forgive me.

Answer (score 0):

Learning the "language" of the CISSP exam is sometimes harder than internalizing the material!

My understanding (as someone who recently passed my CISSP exam) is that "phishing" is defined by the attack relying on some sort of deception or a deceptive practice. So in this case, I would say the key point to focus on when reading this question is the way it is being asked.

It's not a very well-worded question, I admit. BUT to defend it a bit, I'll say that focusing on the implication that "allowing the OpenID relying party to control the connection" is being done voluntarily by whoever is in charge of brokering that connection, lends credence to the phishing answer being "more correct" than the one you provided.